# JQuery - offset.top - add 80px to returned value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a website where I have smooth scrolling implemented. When the user clicks the link to some position on my page, the animation is executed to target's `offset.top` I need to add 80px to this value and then scroll to this element.
Here is the code I'm using right now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      var hash = this.hash;

      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 500, function() {

      window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could it be $(hash).offset().top+80 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top + 80
```

Comment: Onemore question. By default it's pixels, but will it work with... let's say vh? ( - I'm still new to JQuery)

Comment: I think you can do something like `scrollTop: "10vh"` just give it some testing

Comment: But $(hash).offset().top will return value in pixels

Comment: @FalsePride no, you should use pixels, if you need 10vh, you can use `scrollTop: window.innerHeight * 10`